# encode url having Xpath in Query String

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to send title of news to some other page through query string. My title is dynamic so it may contain '&' or other special characters. So I tried this

```
  <a href="NewsByTitle.aspx?title=<%#HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("title"))%>"
```

But I am getting error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments"
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with this code:

```
<a href='NewsByTitle.aspx?title=<%#Server.UrlEncode( XPath("@title").ToString()) %>' ><%# XPath("@title") %></a>
```